# AngularJS and WebAPI CORS

Tags: javascript, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, cors

Is CORS problem on WebAPI stupid or is it me?
Aren't web services suppose to be consumed by third parties?  Can somebody please explain to me why am having problem calling the WebAPI if it was on a different domain, Its a web services, its suppose to be on a different domain!

I added the CORS library to my WebAPI and added the enable inside my config, but still not working.

And who's brilliant idea was to make two calls just to get the info with CORS.  Now all my requests will be doubled !?

How can I fix the CORS problem between AngularJS and Webapi? It would be really nice if somebody can explain to me theoretically, why can't I call my web service without this CORS thingyy. Aren't web service suppose to be consumed by all?

Comment: Please consider clarifying what you want help with and remove random ranting from the post. There is really no problem with CORS on WebAPI :)

Comment: How to fix the CORS problem between AngularJS and WebAPI? I would appreciate it if you explain theoretically why i need CORS in the first place. Why can't I call the web service without any OPTIONS and what not...

Comment: CORS has nothing specifically to do with AngularJS and the WebAPI. Your browser is seeing two different URLs really, maybe becuase they are on different ports perhaps? It's the browser that is more than likely the culprit here.

Get the two applications on the same port or domain (such as services.yourdomain.com and app.yourdomain.com) and you won't have CORS issues.

Comment: Each is deployed on a sub domain.  They share the same parent domain.  However, its not working.  In the future, am gona need to make a request outside the domain since I will be hosting two systems...

Answer (score 0):

CORS problem wouldn't happen on WebAPI part. it will be always in Client side part when WebAPI and client will be in two different ports.

if it is ASP.NET WebAPI you need to install the Microsoft.Owin.Cors package and initialize CORS in the startup of the web server.

In the WebiApiConfig.cs put in something like:

```
    var cors = new EnabledCorsAttribute("", "", "DataServiceVersion,MaxDataServiceVersion"); 
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

**Web.Config**

```
<httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: The WebAPI and Client are deployed on different sub domain. I installed Web API CORS 2.2 and added the config.EnableCors(). but it didnt work.  Is it any different then OWIN CORS ?